# Cypress assertion for element propery

Tags: cypress

I'm writing a test in cypress to test if a video is playing. Unfortunately, this can't be achieved through code such as:

```js
cy.get('video')
  .should('have.prop', 'paused', false)
  .and('have.prop', 'ended', false);
```

I do have an a solution in mind that I'm having trouble executing. The video element has a property `currentTime` that will be higher than 0 if the video is streaming. I've tried several ways of declaring this to a variable and making an assertion based on that variable.

```js
cy.get('video')
  .should('have.prop', 'currentTime')
  .then((x) => {
    // x is the class prop
    expect(x).to.be.greaterThan('0');
  });
```

However, cypress doesn't interpret the value as an integer. Any advice on how I could go about this problem?

Comment: this link might help you https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/test-video-play/

Comment: Couldn't you just cast X to a number? `expect(Number(x)).to.be.greaterThan('0')`?

Comment: Can you add the html showing the property `currentTime `?

Answer (score 0):

The `currentTime` prop is already a number, but you compare it a string, so Cypress gives you the message

> AssertionError: the argument to above must be a number

This refers to `'0'`, not `x`.

Try

```js
expect(x).to.be.greaterThan(0);
```